# when i run this function it just gives the reachabilty graph

Tags: graph, reachability, petri-net

I am trying to produce the coverabilty graph for any petri net using a function i already have for the reachabilty but a keep getting the reachability graph no matter the input here is the function

```
                def calculate_coverability_graph(num_places, num_transitions, markings_vector, incidence_matrix, weight_matrix, looped_weight_matrix):
                    markings_vector = markings_vector.astype(object)

                    def can_fire(markings_vector, incidence_matrix, weight_matrix):
                        fireable_transitions = []

                        for i in range(num_transitions):
                            def can_fire_transition(marking, transition=i):
                                for j in range(len(incidence_matrix)):
                                    if incidence_matrix[j][transition] == -1:
                                        if marking[j] != 'ω' and marking[j] < weight_matrix[j][transition]:
                                            return False
                                return True

                            if can_fire_transition(markings_vector):
                                fireable_transitions.append(i)

                        return fireable_transitions

                    coverability_graph = nx.DiGraph()
                    markings_list = [tuple(markings_vector.flatten())]
                    coverability_graph.add_node(0)

                    queue = deque([(0, markings_vector)])

                    counter = 0
                    while queue:
                        if counter >= 100:
                            break

                        parent_index, parent_markings = queue.popleft()

                        for t in can_fire(parent_markings, incidence_matrix, weight_matrix):
                            new_markings = parent_markings.copy()
                            for j in range(len(incidence_matrix)):
                                if incidence_matrix[j][t] == -1:
                                    if new_markings[j] != 'ω':
                                        new_markings[j] -= weight_matrix[j][t]
                                elif incidence_matrix[j][t] == 1:
                                    if new_markings[j] != 'ω':
                                        new_markings[j] += weight_matrix[j][t]

                            # Update the new markings with looped_weight_matrix only for fired transitions
                            for j in range(len(incidence_matrix)):
                                if looped_weight_matrix[j][t] > 0 and new_markings[j] != 'ω':
                                    new_markings[j] += looped_weight_matrix[j][t]

                            for i, (old, new) in enumerate(zip(parent_markings, new_markings)):
                                if not isinstance(old, str) and not isinstance(new, str) and new > old:
                                    omega_reached = False
                                    for ancestor in nx.ancestors(coverability_graph, parent_index):
                                        ancestor_markings = markings_list[ancestor]
                                        if ancestor_markings[i] == 'ω' or (not isinstance(ancestor_markings[i], str) and not isinstance(new, str) and new > ancestor_markings[i]):
                                            omega_reached = True
                                            break
                                    if omega_reached:
                                        new_markings[i] = 'ω'

                            try:
                                child_index = markings_list.index(tuple(new_markings.flatten()))
                            except ValueError:
                                child_index = len(markings_list)
                                markings_list.append(tuple(new_markings.flatten()))
                                coverability_graph.add_node(child_index)
                                queue.append((child_index, new_markings))

                            coverability_graph.add_edge(parent_index, child_index, transition=t)

                        counter += 1

                    return coverability_graph, markings_list
```

i think the issue is in denoting the omega value but i have no clue what it is or why its happening

Comment: I fixed the code formatting for you. Next time, make sure it's readable. There's a preview below the question field.